# Testing a bootloader written from scratch?

Tags: testing, virtual-machine, x86

I'm planning to write a simple bootloader. Nothing too complicated. Just really basic output and maybe keyboard input.
But it seems a bit crazy to restart my computer every time I want to run the bootloader. 
I have a vmware workstation license. Could I just create a VM and use it to boot my image or does vmware only support existing operating systems?
I also heard you can use "x86 emulators", but I have no idea which one I should get.

I'll use Ubuntu to write and compile the bootloader btw.

Comment: Yes, you could. A simple search here will show you many people doing just that.

Comment: I did more than one simple search. I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Oh, my mind was on Stack Overflow. Search there and you'll see many people using different virtual machines for testing.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Looks like Virtualbox is the way to go then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257986/how-to-test-a-bootloader

Answer (score 3):

There's a good getting-started tutorial [here](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html). In the tutorial they use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page), an x86 emulator. It's not a full-featured as VirtualBox, but if you're just testing a boot loader, it may be better as it's a more lightweight package and you'll probably be in a pretty tight edit->compile->test loop.